# Refactor highlight matched word in string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, regex

I have following method which highlight matched word in text:

```
# Hightlight matched term
#
# Ex(for term: some):
#   "<span class="bold">Some</span> CEO Event"
#
def highlight_matched(matched_word, text)
  regex = matched_word.gsub(/\*|\"|\'/, "")
                       .split(" ")
                       .map { |s| "\\b#{s}" }.join('|')

  text.gsub(/(#{regex})/i, '<span class="bold">\1</span>')
end
```

Is there a better solution for that?

I am using it here:

```
"%s %s" %[highlight_matched(title[0..70]), content_tag(:span, caption, class: 'search-type')]
```

Comment: Is `text` pure text or HTML? can you add to the question some asserts?

Comment: Text is ``HTML``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `text` may contain HTML (in that case `text` is a somewhat misleading variable name) you definitely should use a HTML parser. What about this? (adding a `<p>` as wrapper, otherwise xpath won't find parent text nodes).

```
require 'nokogiri'

def highlight(html, word)
  Nokogiri::HTML::fragment("<p>" + html + "</p>").tap do |doc|
    doc.search('.//text()').each do |text_node|
      new_contents = text_node.text.gsub(/\b(#{word})\b/i, '<span class="bold">\1</span>')
      text_node.replace(new_contents)
    end
  end.xpath("p").inner_html
end

puts highlight('<p><a href="http://runner.com">Run Rabbit Run</a></p>', "run")
# <p><a href="http://runner.com"><span class="bold">Run</span>     
# Rabbit <span class="bold">Run</span></a></p>
```

Comment: hmm, it not works for me: https://gist.github.com/b5015d8932990efc786b

Comment: sometimes text has HTML tags sometimes not, like above

Comment: Here is my output: https://gist.github.com/a03d7b44aa70cb6e0345

Comment: I am using ``1.9.3``and nokogiri ``1.5.5``

Comment: oh, I see, the problem is that xpath won't get parent text nodes.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a better class name, such as `highlighted` or `search-term` or `search-match`.

## Bug

Your solution will break anchors, or titles, or other hmtl properties:

```
# Yields: "Broken <a href='http://www.example.org/<span>cat</span>nip'>example</a>."
puts highlight_matched("cat", "Broken <a href='http://catnip.com'>example</a>.")
```

### Another potential problem

And if you repeatedly run it on the same text with a list of words, you will get nested replacements if you don't have the words sorted by size-descending and replace a word ("cat") that is a substring of a previous replacement ("catnip").

This might be, or not, a problem.
For me it was, because I was replacing with anchors and HTML does not allow nested anchors.
For you it might be, too, depending on how you wish to style the matches.

```
intermediate = highlight_matched("catnip", "I love catnip!")
# Yields: "I love <span><span>cat</span>nip</span>!"
puts highlight_matched("cat", intermediate)
```